# Best Practise for User Authentication and Sessions in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, session, authentication, ios7

I have an iOS-App which deals with user authentication. I want to authenticate a certain user against my own Rest-Webservice (Built with Rails). After the authentication  was successful I want to keep that session. Lets say if the app gets closed and the user starts the app again no authentication should be neccessary. What is the best practise building such a workflow? Do I send something like a session key on every API call?

Comment: Ask for best practises will never yield any correct answer since they are very much opinion based.

Comment: What if I want certain opinions from experienced developers?

Comment: You will get many answer, none of them will be the same. You will even have a difficult time choosing which one is right for you situation. And some answer that are just wrong. You should just start doing some research on the matter, like `Oauth` and such. Then read about store data in the keychain. This will help you more that other peoples opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach would be, to generate a unique token from Rest web service. When the first time user logs in (or registers with a new account), webservice would generate a unique token and sends it back to the user.

After that, every time app consume a REST endpoint, this token would be passed as a parameter. Token is checked against the current logged in user's active token. If it doesn't match , server would end the session for that user. Token will be cleared from DB when user logs out.

This is how we did multiple projects with REST webservices. Not sure if this is the best practice but definitely works well and requires less effort.